# How to escape the accelerator characters?

Tags: delphi

I'm setting some strings as values for the `Caption` property of a `TLabel` control.

I receive these values from outside and sometimes they contains the `'&'` key, which is interpreted as an accelerator key.

**For example:**

```
var
  NewCaption : string;
begin
  NewCaption := 'B&B';
  MyLabel.Caption := MyNewCaption;
end;
```

At runtime, it appears as `'BB'`, with the second letter underlined:

[image: Picture displaying a TLabel control which Caption's value has ben set to 'B&B']

I would like to display `'B&B'` instead.

---

I know the [`Vcl.Menus.StripHotkey`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel.Caption) function for removing the accelerator character markers...

```
function StripHotkey(const Text: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := Text;
  I := 1;
  while I <= Length(Result) do
  begin
{$IF NOT DEFINED(CLR)}
    if IsLeadChar(Result[I]) then
      Inc(I)
    else
{$ENDIF}
    if Result[I] = cHotkeyPrefix then
      if SysLocale.FarEast and
        ((I > 1) and (Length(Result)-I >= 2) and
         (Result[I-1] = '(') and (Result[I+2] = ')')) then
        Delete(Result, I-1, 4)
      else
        Delete(Result, I, 1);
    Inc(I);
  end;
end;
```

...but I don't know any specific function for escaping the accelerator characters, in order it would be displayed in the `Caption` as the original string (`'B&B'`).

Comment: In this scenario, the right solution is to set the label's `ShowAccelChar` to `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to not show accelerator characters on TLabel you just need to set its [ShowAccelChar](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomLabel.ShowAccelChar) property to `False`.

EDIT: Same goes for [TStaticText](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomStaticText.ShowAccelChar) component as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found is by simply doubling the `'&'` caracter, but didn't find any specific function for this purpouse:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Menus;

...

var
  NewCaption : string;
begin
  NewCaption := 'B&B';
  MyLabel.Caption := StringReplace(MyNewCaption, cHotkeyPrefix, cHotkeyPrefix + cHotkeyPrefix, [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

I would like to know if there are better solutions